# PDF cannot display Chinese fonts in table of contents

Tags: pdf, acrobat

I made a PDF file from Latex (using TexMaker).

Acrobat Reader is able to display BOTH the text and the table of contents in *Linux*.

But Acrobat Reader is unable to display the table of contents in *Windows XP* (the Chinese characters came out as boxes).  However, the text is displayed correctly.

I tried to embed the fonts into the PDF but the various methods are not 100% successful, so I'm not sure if the fonts are embedded correctly or not.  Anyway, the table of contents remain unreadable in Windows.

I wonder if it is really an font embedding problem?  Or do I need to install these "Adobe Reader X Font Packs":

```
https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4883
```

My concern is that I'd like my PDF to be readable in Windows, including the table of contents (and preferably without further installations).  If this is possible...

Comment: By "Table of Contents" do you mean a table of contents that is in the textual content of the document *or* do you actually mean "bookmarks" which are the hierarchical structure of the document displayed separately in the bookmark pane?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are talking about "bookmarks" and not saying part of the text in the document is ok and part is not. PDF Bookmarks are part of the UI of the application and are not selected from embedded fonts. Therefore, the system you are running on needs to know how to handle fonts in the language(s) of choice.

See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1144972?start=0&tstart=0

Embedding the fonts will have no effect on the bookmarks.